# Mediawiki redirect from old URL path starting with /w/ to new path without it

Tags: apache, url, redirect, mediawiki

I have old URL path for all pages

```
example.com/w/Page_title
```

Now I changed it to

```
example.com/Page_title
```

using [Short URL manual for Apache](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache)

And the question is:
How to make 301 redirects from old path for users that coming back using bookmarks?

my LocalSettings.php

```
$wgForceHTTPS = true;

$wgScriptPath = "/wiki";
$wgArticlePath = "/$1";
```

and mod_rewrite:

```sh
RewriteEngine On
# Short URL for wiki pages
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]
# Redirect Main Page to /
RewriteRule ^/*$ /index.php?title=Main_Page [L,QSA]
RewriteRule .*\.ico$ - [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `RewriteRule` to do the redirect before the other rules:

```sh
RewriteRule ^\/?w\/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This matches any URL that starts with `/w/` and redirects to remove it.

- `^` - Starts with
- `\/?` - An optional starting slash so this rule will work in different contexts (Apache conf and .htaccess)
- `w\/` - The `w/` directory
- `(.*)` - Everything after the `w/` in a capturing group that becomes `$1` in the target
- `/$1` - Where to redirect to
- `R=301` Make this a permanent (301) redirect
- `L` - Make this the last rewrite rule so that the other rules don't get processed when it matches.

In the end it should look like this with your other rules:

```sh
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect old URLs that start with /w/
RewriteRule ^\/?w\/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
# Short URL for wiki pages
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]
# Redirect Main Page to /
RewriteRule ^/*$ /index.php?title=Main_Page [L,QSA]
RewriteRule .*\.ico$ - [L]
```

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite I added that